# Windows RDP behind NAT, with Cloudflare Tunnel

Tags: windows, cloudflare

My internet connection is behind NAT, which makes it impossible to serve anything outside (security cameras, file servers, ecc)

I'm trying CloudFlare Zero Trust Tunnel to bypass it, and it seems to work fine. I ran the Windows installer, ran this cmd:

```
cloudflared.exe service install CLOUDFLARE_TOKEN_HERE
```

And cofigured the tunnel like this:

[image]

Now if I connect to `emby.example.com`, I can see my website, locally hosted on port `8096`, from an external computer.

What I can't do is connect to Windows RDP: it is locally active on port `3389`, with "Require Network Level Authentication" disabled. However, if I open RDP client on an external computer and connect to `rdp://rdp.example.com` the client simply doesn't find anything. Why?

Comment: This *should* work, how is your Windows Firewall configured?

Comment: I believe you  need to run the cloudflared local proxy service on your client a-la: https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/connections/connect-networks/use-cases/rdp/#connect-to-rdp-server-with-cloudflared-access. I haven't yet found a way round it like web sites just working. I need this for SSH too.